# file open in ofstream fails with no admin privileges c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using the following code to open a file in my program.

> ```
> CString cstrOut;
> CString cstrFileName;
> cstrFileName.Format( "FinalSect%1d.txt", nSect+1 );
> std::ofstream echofile;
> echofile.open(cstrFileName);
> ```

This works fine but when I open a file without admin rights it can not be opened.
Please help me.

Comment: So basically you want to know how to bypass file permissions?  This question makes no sense.

Comment: Is that file located on C: drive, and under Windows 7?

Comment: @George>ya.it opens other files without problem. thanks.

Comment: It depends on **where** you attempt to create the file. Ordinary users have limited access to some places, like system directories or other users' files.

Comment: It's related to User Access Control. A regular user has limited access to C: drive, and Administrator has full access to C: drive (assuming C: is the partition where Windows is installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to **User Access Control**. A regular user has limited access to **C:** drive, and **Administrator** has full access to **C:** drive (assuming C: is the partition where **Windows** is installed).

Either make your application register for the **UAC** (if it is a non trivial application intended for other users, comercial or otherwise) or run **Visual Studio** (I'm assuming you are using VS, but applies to other IDEs as well) as Administrator (either form context menu, or edit shortcut properties). Or you can work on a different partition than the one where **Windows** is installed.